# Can I change my MacOSx version 10.7.5 from 64-bit to 32-bit mode? If so, how?

Tags: macos, usb, 64-bit, 32-bit

I recently purchased some logitech accessories and my computer will not recognize the tiny USB they provided unless I plug it into an additional wire component they provided, thus defeating the purpose of the tiny-forget-about-it-niffty USB. I read that this is because all MACs were switched to 64-bit and supposedly there is a way to convert back and forth between 64-32. Please advise, thanks in advance!

Comment: I apologize if I sounds like I don't know what I'm talking about... because its true.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what Mac and what Logitech device you have? All Macs since late 2006 are 64-bit, and I really doubt this causes the problem. FWIW I have the Performance Mouse MX with Unifying Receiver and it works without any problems on my 2010 Macbook Pro.

Comment: Here are the instructions for switching modes: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3773

Comment: Of course, I am using the Logitech MK520 mouse and keyboard with unifying usb and my computer is a 2011 MacBook Pro. Thanks so much, I'll give it the college try

Comment: Gave it a try and my laptop successfully booted in 32-bit mode but the unifying usb still didn't work when directly plugged into my USB port. Drat, thought that was gonna be the ticket.

Comment: Have you tried another USB port?  The wire thingy they provide is just that, nothing more, a wire.  Cannot have an effect unless your usb port is bent/skewed/dirty, or the receiver is bent/skewed/dirty. My pre-edit answer included repairing the receiver with the mouse (d/l the Unifying Receiver software from the Logitech site), this may help too.

Comment: I did, both USB port wouldn't pick up the small unifyer by itself. :(